# How to get the elements into a list in appium

Tags: android, appium, test-project, testproject.io

```
List<WebElement> count=  driver.findElements(by.xpath("abc"));
```

I am getting an error if I use the above line:

```
"Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<WebElement>"
```

I am doing a **TestProject** coded android test

Answer (score 0):

If you check `findElements` method in source code:

```java
    @Override public List<T> findElements(By by) {
        return super.findElements(by);
    }
```

The T is a type parameter passed to the generic interface List. In order to use it, you must define the type in your code:

```java
List<MobileElement> count = driver.findElements(by.xpath("abc"));
```